# How contact sql with tableau so that if there was a mistake in report he marked it as red?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

Suppose i have data source for tableau to perform report.
dbo.myreport
Also i check is the value(s) right or wrong?
Let me provide picture to be more clear
[image]

i create query that check is the value(s) right or wrong. For example 6,6 is wrong and in dbo.checkmyreport i have structure

```
date;variable;value;right-wrong
07.05.2021;x1;6,6;wrong
```

how to do to if value from dbo.checkmyreport marked is wrong then it must automatically must be marked as red in tableau report.
Is there possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have already added this data into Tableau and kept the column names as such right? And you have already created the desired bar chart.

In Tableau add the "right-wrong" dimension to the Color marks and set the colors as appropriate. That should let you color all the bars that are labelled as "wrong" in a specific color.